# How to "stick" widgets to bottom of an expanding window?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator

I have a bunch of standard qt creator dragged-on controls, which I have at the bottom of a window. I have one table widget that I want to expand vertically to be able to display more rows if the window is expanded downwards, less if upwards to a minimum. I want all the other widgets to stick to the bottom of the window as that edge moves. I'm using Qt Creator 2.1.0 and Qt 4.7, and I don't see any flags for the widgets that would do what I need, nor did googling really turn up anything enlightening. Perhaps it has something to do with putting the widgets in a container that moves and/or stretches? Right now, they're just on MainWindow.

Comment: This question would be better if you mentioned whether you use any layouts: the answers will be very different depending on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set a vertical layout, add a spacer to it, and then your widget. The spacer will push your widget all the way down. Additionally you might want to toy around with the size policies.

Comment: I'll look into that. Need to back it up first. :)

Comment: @fyngyrz Ahh, you're not using version control? You should. It's trivial, it doesn't need a central repository, just `git init` then `git add -A` and finally `git commit -m "Initial commit"`. And from thereon it's smooth sailing. I suggest a graphical client like smartgit, worth every penny but not absolutely necessary of course.

Comment: @ddriver you were closest, so you get the checkmark. Here's what you have to do. Make your layout (which I had done) and then, voodoo: You click on the window so as to select it, and not your layout, then select "lay out in a grid" from the context menu. This (somehow) grabs your layout downstream without you having to do anything, attaches to the window upstream, and viola, everything stretches. Hopefully that will help someone else who is trying to overcome the Designer voodoo.

Comment: @kuba-ober yeah, I'm a git user. However, this wasn't even the ghost of an app yet, as I couldn't get the form to play right. Now I'll be writing some code, and git will be involved. But thanks. Spot on.

Comment: What is a spacer? I don't see anything called spacer in the widget box?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to know what you are trying to do from your question, but perhaps you are looking for [QSplitter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsplitter.html).

Alternatively, you can specify various [QLayout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlayout.html)s for a QWidget, such as [QHBoxLayout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qhboxlayout.html), [QVBoxLayout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qvboxlayout.html), [QGridLayout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgridlayout.html), etc. Various widgets can be added to the layout you specify, then you set the layout on a QWidget, so it acts as a container for the widgets you've added to the layout. Stretching and alignment flags can be set as you add your widgets to the layout.

Comment: Thank you. I'll see what I can figure out, appreciate the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

A `QMainWindow` should only be used if you need its docking functionality. Otherwise, just use a plain `QWidget`. No general purpose child widgets can be "stuck" onto a `QMainWindow`. They need to belong to the central widget. All you most likely need to do is to set an `Expanding` vertical size policy to the table widget. Designer should do it by default. Here's an example:

#### mainwindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QTableWidget" name="table">
      <row>
       <property name="text">
        <string>1</string>
       </property>
      </row>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Name</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <property name="text">
        <string>fyngyrz</string>
       </property>
      </item>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="foo">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Foo</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="bar">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Bar</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to represent my circumstance. The table is set to expand. But it doesn't. Perhaps it needs to be inside something else. In any case, the only thing that moves is the size window corner and the window edges.

Comment: @fyngyrz Post a minimized .ui file in your question, then. Or compare the one you have to the one I posted: they are rather simple XML, it should be self-explanatory. Looks to me like you don't have any layouts in your design.

Comment: The layout is within designer. So what I get is a mainwindow, with a central widget, into which I can drop... well, whatever. This has the salutary effect of allowing precision widget positioning and sizing without any interference from Qt, so I was hoping to use it as it stood. I've not had any luck with that as yet - seems like everything has to be dropped into Qt's various "I will size it for you" grids and so on, which pretty much breaks what I was trying to do. The only thing that _didn't_ work was having the various widgets at the bottom stick to the window edge. Subclass and move... meh

Comment: further: I got the stick-to-the-bottom behavior I wanted with the "right click on window and lay out in a grid" vooddo, but I also ended up with Qt resizing a bunch of things I really, really didn't want it to resize. I thought the issue was simple - apparently I was wrong. It seemed to me like it _ought_ to have been simple. :) The amount that I don't understand about designer far exceeds what I do.

Comment: You can set any widget you want to have a fixed size, and you can set the layout to have zero margin and zero spacing. That should do 99% of what you want, most likely. Otherwise, you'll have to manage the child widget geometry yourself, just as you would if you wrote native WIN32 code. Override the parent's `resizeEvent` and voila. I guess I admire your perseverance if you implemented sdrdx without a single layout, but it might not have been all necessary. The widget size policies only have meaning to layouts (or your own code), otherwise there's no use to them.

Comment: Qt Designer is a way to graphically generate widget-instantiating code (`foo.ui` file -> `uic` -> `ui_foo.h`). You can use Designer to come up with almost anything you could write by hand that doesn't require iteration to generate widgets. You don't need to use Designer at all. Most of the code you'd have to write is trivial, see most anything here:  https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions

Comment: Ha, no, sdrdx is loaded with layouts. I'm persistent, but I'm not *crazy*. Plus, in that case, qt's designer did very much what I wanted to do. That doesn't seem to be the case here. As for your latter remark, I use qt designer because it makes many things easier, and I'd much rather write signal processing code than GUI code. "Drop widget, go to slot" is very attractive as such things go. If the first word that comes to mind is "lazy", then mea culpa veritas.

Comment: I just got it working exactly as I wanted to. Group boxes (with the titles cleared out) gave me the freedom to position I wanted, while (eventually) fiddling with the sizes, policies, and stretchifiers made it behave. Everyone here encouraged me one way or another. No one even told me I was being an idiot. :)

Comment: Of course use a group box only if you need its groupie look. Otherwise, use a `QFrame`. If you don't need any visual indication of grouping, use a plain old `QWidget` or just a child layout if you use layouts. Qt Designer is sometimes a pain to use when you deal with child layouts so personally I often mock up the XML directly, and then open it up for final tweaks in Designer.

Comment: I don't mind the subtle box look, and in truth, the controls are kind of in two sets. [Here's the working result](http://www.blish.org/sdrdxdoc/swdb.html) (picture at the top.)

Comment: @fyngyrz It looks very much non-native in how you stack those group boxes: there's three of them - an outer one and two inner ones. It'd look much better to have just one outer group box and then a horizontal divider line between the section. IMHO of course, but that agrees with Apple's HIG I'd think too.

Comment: Thanks,  Kuba. Appreciate the feedback. I'll see if I can do it without breaking everything. Designer is a little tricky for me.

Comment: @fyngyrz If you have a decent xml editor, it might be easier to mess with the .ui file itself - at least I find it easier sometimes.

Comment: I don't have anything outside of Designer but a 10.6.8 text editor; most of the cool stuff made these days won't run under 10.6.8 anyway. I'm not particularly XML friendly, either. [I did get it going.](http://www.blish.org/sdrdxdoc/swdb.html) Yesterday's confusion has abated somewhat. Or I was lucky. :)Thanks again.